# what is 0xFF and 0x33 means?

Tags: php, colors, rgb, pixel

For example when I read pixel color from an image, why I should use

```
$r = round(round($rgb['red'] / 0x33) * 0x33);
$g = round(round($rgb['green'] / 0x33) * 0x33);
$b = round(round($rgb['blue'] / 0x33) * 0x33);
```

I'm trying to feagure it out the right hexa color of rgb when breaking a part pixel by pixel and image.

Comment: 0x.. is a notation for hexadecimal numbers: 0xff is 255 so the maximum number on a byte. 0x33 is 51, so you can partition 256 values into 6 classes. It is just a method to quantize the colours into 6 values per channel